# About connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $X, \, Y \subset M$, and $X, Y, M$ are connected. If $\partial X \subset Y$, then $X \cup Y$ is connected.

I know that, if $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ then $X \cup Y$ is connected. I think that the condition $\partial X \subset Y$ implies that same $x \in X$ belongs to $Y$, but I can't do that. Can anyone give a suggestion?

Comment: Proof by contradiction is one way to approach this - suppose there is a separation of  $X\cup Y$ and show that this implies there exists $x\in\partial X$ with $x\notin Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X\cup Y$ is not connected.

Then $X\cup Y\notin\left\{ X,Y\right\} $
so that $X\neq\varnothing$ and $Y\neq\varnothing$ and non-empty
sets $A,B$ must exist $\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap\overline{B}$
and $A\cup B=X\cup Y$.

Then $X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$ since $X$ is connected, and
similarly $Y\subseteq A$ or $Y\subseteq B$.

$X,Y\subseteq A$ and $X,Y\subseteq B$ both cannot be true, and WLOG
we may assume that $X\subseteq A$ and $Y\subseteq B$.

Then $\partial X\subseteq\overline{A}$ and $\partial X\subseteq Y\subseteq B$
so that $\partial X\subseteq\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing$ which
means that $X$ is a clopen set.

But as shown we have $X\neq\varnothing$ and - because $Y\neq\varnothing$-
also $X\neq M$.

This means that $M$ is not connected, so a contradiction is found.